# Oracle every two records into one

Tags: sql, oracle

Hello I have been trying to accomplish the following:

```
key1, key2, val1, userid, receipttype, val2,val3,val4,date,val5
1   0   0   1   3   0   0   0   18-JAN-17   1
1   0   0   1   4   0   0   0   18-JAN-17   1
1   0   0   114 3   0   0   0   18-JAN-17   1
1   0   0   114 4   0   0   0   18-JAN-17   1
1   0   0   1   3   0   0   0   18-JAN-17   1
1   0   0   1   4   0   0   0   18-JAN-17   1
```

This table I'm trying to somehow get the following results:

```
key1, key2, val1, userid, receipttype, val2,val3,val4,date,val5,key1, key2, val1, userid, receipttype, val2,val3,val4,date,val5
1,0,0,1,3,0,0,0,18-JAN-17,1 1,0,0,1 4,0,0,0,18-JAN-17,1
1,0,0,114,3,0,0,0,18-JAN-17,1 1,0,0,114 4,0,0,0,18-JAN-17,1
```

I work a lot with inner joins but that definitely won't help me here.
I've worked with pivot but that also doesn't really seem to help me here.

Not entirely sure what I could use to get the desired results.

So I need to pair two records into one.
For every record that has a 3 I need to pair it with a second record that has a 4 and the userid must also be the same.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is an inner join.  You need to list your table twice.

Assuming your table is called `tbl`:

```
SELECT a.key1, b.key1
FROM tbl a INNER JOIN tbl b ON a.userid = b.userid
WHERE a.receipttype = 3
AND b.receipttype = 4
```

Comment: Hi WW wouldn't an inner join not work in the case where there are multiple records with user id of 1?

Comment: If there are multiple records, how do you expect them to be paired?  What decides what goes with what?  Or do you want to squash the result down to one row?

Comment: I'm ordering by date so for every 3 there should be a paired 4.
UserID 1
Record has 3
Record has 4
These are ordered by date and these two should be paired.

But there could be multiple UserIDs of 1 that is the tricky part.

In other words for every two records I need to stick them together.

Comment: So should there be 3 rows in your desired results?

Comment: Is this just not possible?

Comment: It's possible.  You'll need to use the `row_number()` to give each row a number within it's group of userid and receipttype, and then extend my query above to join on row_number() as well.

Comment: Using Row_number() i was able to accomplish what I needed, going to mark your answer as the answer since it did help